# JOOQ is not generating classes

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jooq

I have a problem with JOOQ framework (3.13.4) along with Spring Boot and Java 8.

The problem is that I'm trying to generate domain classes using java code way (instead of using codegen plugin with maven which had some troubles with custom naming strategy provider). So as first let me show You the *@Configuration* class which contains (at least I believe that it contains) all of the necessary beans:

```
import com.ormtester.common.base.Measurer;
import com.ormtester.common.utils.enums.OrmType;
import com.ormtester.datasources.config.RouteableDataSource;
import org.jooq.SQLDialect;
import org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool;
import org.jooq.impl.DataSourceConnectionProvider;
import org.jooq.impl.DefaultConfiguration;
import org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext;
import org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteListenerProvider;
import org.jooq.util.xml.jaxb.Schema;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.jooq.meta.jaxb.*;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JooqConfigurator {

    private Properties moduleProperties;

    private RouteableDataSource routeableDataSource;

    public JooqConfigurator(RouteableDataSource routeableDataSource) {
        this.routeableDataSource = routeableDataSource;
        try {
            moduleProperties = new Properties();
            moduleProperties.load(JooqConfigurator.class.getClassLoader()
                    .getResourceAsStream("jooq.properties"));
        } catch (Exception ignore) {}
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceConnectionProvider connectionProvider() {
        return new DataSourceConnectionProvider(routeableDataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public ExceptionTranslator exceptionTransformer() {
        return new ExceptionTranslator();
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultConfiguration configuration() {
        DefaultConfiguration jooqConfiguration = new DefaultConfiguration();
        jooqConfiguration.set(connectionProvider());
        jooqConfiguration.set(new DefaultExecuteListenerProvider(exceptionTransformer()));
        jooqConfiguration.set(SQLDialect.DEFAULT);
        return jooqConfiguration;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultDSLContext dsl() {
        return new DefaultDSLContext(configuration());
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void generateCode() {
        try {
            GenerationTool.generate(new org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Configuration()
                    .withJdbc(new Jdbc()
                            .withDriver("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")
                            .withUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ormtester?useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC")
                            .withUser("root")
                            .withPassword("root123"))
                    .withGenerator(new Generator()
                            .withName("org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator")
                            .withStrategy(new CustomStrategyProvider())
                            .withDatabase(new Database()
                                    .withName("org.jooq.meta.mysql.MySQLDatabase")
                                    .withIncludes(".*")
                                    .withExcludes("")
                                    .withSchemata(new SchemaMappingType().withInputSchema("ormtester").withOutputSchema("ormtester"))
                                    .withInputCatalog("ormtester")
                                    .withOutputCatalog("ormtester"))
                            .withTarget(new Target()
                                    .withPackageName("com.ormtester.jooq.domain")
                                    .withDirectory("jooq/src/main/java"))));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

RouteableDataSource is a type that extends *AbstractRoutingDataSource* because in this case I need to have a possibility to change datasource at runtime. This thing is working well in the other regions of the project (or in another words with tools like Hibernate or MyBatis).

As You can see there is a *@PostConstruct* method which is used for generating domain classes and the problem is that this method doesn't generate any error or something but the classes are also not generated. I've tried to run it using PostgreSQL and Oracle database (of course changing the driver, database name etc.) and the situation is looking exactly the same.

One interesting thing is that when I'm running this code and package *com.ormtester.jooq.domain* is present - during the method execution *domain* package is getting removed.

I'd also like to mention that JOOQ autoconfiguration is disabled by excluding *JooqAutoConfiguration* class through the *@SpringBootApplication* annotation located at the project's main (starter) class.

IDE is running in administrator's mode and - what can be also interesting - if I will set the breakpoint in the *getJavaClassName()* method in my custom naming strategy provided (*CustomStrategyProvider* which extends *DefaultGeneratorStrategy* class, the breakpoint is reached everytime this method is used.

So does anyone faced the same problem and/or simply can tell me if I'm doing something wrong or something is missing in the code snippet that I've provieded here? I have this problem since about 4 days and now I'm running out of the ideas what can be wrong. I went through the tons of topics on many forums and nothing helped me, including the tutorials on the author's page (which in my opinion simply lacks of important informations).

I'll be really grateful for every help - thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Code generation is a build task, not a runtime task. I can't think of a reasonable scenario where generating code only at runtime would make sense.

> The problem is that I'm trying to generate domain classes using java code way (instead of using codegen plugin with maven which had some troubles with custom naming strategy provider)

You have to create a separate maven module (or project) where you build the custom naming strategy, and then add that as a dependency to the jOOQ code generation plugin. This works the same way as with the [`JPADatabase`, where entities have to be placed in a separate maven module](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-jpa/).

Comment: I have added the edit to the question where I'm trying to do the things as in the tutorial under the link You have given in the answer. Could you help me with the next problem I've faced?

Comment: @MarcinSobolewski: Thanks for the update. That's a new question, not really related to your original one. The way Stack Overflow works is you create a new question for this, because: 1) the old one is in itself already useful for some future reader who finds it, 2) when you edit a question to keep adding new, unrelated stuff, future readers (including me) will find it hard to understand what the sequence of problems was. I'll be looking out for your new question. I suggest reverting the edit on this one.

Comment: I have reverted the current post and removed the EDIT section. Then I've posted a new topic as You mentioned above, here is the link: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64323370/jooq-does-not-generating-classes-jpadatabase)

Comment: @MarcinSobolewski Thanks a lot :) I'll look into it right away.