# JOOQ does not generating classes (JPADatabase)

Tags: java, mysql, maven, jpa, jooq

I have a problem with JOOQ framework (3.13.5) along with Spring Boot and Java 8. I'm trying to generate domain classes following the instructions from the manual given on the author's page ([link](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-jpa/)) using the *GenerationTool* from JOOQ, which is mentioned [here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-configuration/). The project structure is presented below:

[image]

The *domain* package contains JPA entities. Then I've added run configuration, where as the main class I've marked the *GenerationTool* from JOOQ's library with argument: /jooq-config.xml (as mentioned in the author's manual linked above). The config file content is shown below:

```
<configuration xmlns="http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.13.0.xsd">
<generator>
    <database>
        <name>org.jooq.meta.extensions.jpa.JPADatabase</name>
        <properties>
            <property>
                <key>packages</key>
                <value>com.ormtester.jpa.domain</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <key>useAttributeConverters</key>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <key>unqualifiedSchema</key>
                <value>none</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <key>hibernate.physical_naming_strategy</key>
                <value>org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy</value>
            </property>
        </properties>
    </database>
</generator>
```

For the analyse issues I'm also adding the the fragment of pom.xml with lib's versions:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
        <artifactId>jooq-meta-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>3.13.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
        <artifactId>jooq-codegen</artifactId>
        <version>3.13.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And now when I'm trying to build the project, I'm getting the following error:

```
18:49:37.330 [main] WARN org.jooq.util.jaxb.tools.MiniJAXB - org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 72; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'configuration'.
18:49:42.215 [main] INFO org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool - Initialising properties  : /jooq-config.xml
18:49:43.134 [main] DEBUG org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool - Input configuration      : <onError>FAIL</onError><generator><name>org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGenerator</name><database><name>org.jooq.meta.extensions.jpa.JPADatabase</name><regexMatchesPartialQualification>true</regexMatchesPartialQualification><sqlMatchesPartialQualification>true</sqlMatchesPartialQualification><includes>.*</includes><excludes></excludes><includeExcludeColumns>false</includeExcludeColumns><includeTables>true</includeTables><includeEmbeddables>true</includeEmbeddables><includeRoutines>true</includeRoutines><includeTriggerRoutines>false</includeTriggerRoutines><includePackages>true</includePackages><includePackageRoutines>true</includePackageRoutines><includePackageUDTs>true</includePackageUDTs><includePackageConstants>true</includePackageConstants><includeUDTs>true</includeUDTs><includeSequences>true</includeSequences><includeIndexes>true</includeIndexes><includePrimaryKeys>true</includePrimaryKeys><includeUniqueKeys>true</includeUniqueKeys><includeForeignKeys>true</includeForeignKeys><includeCheckConstraints>true</includeCheckConstraints><includeInvisibleColumns>true</includeInvisibleColumns><recordVersionFields></recordVersionFields><recordTimestampFields></recordTimestampFields><syntheticIdentities></syntheticIdentities><syntheticPrimaryKeys></syntheticPrimaryKeys><overridePrimaryKeys></overridePrimaryKeys><dateAsTimestamp>false</dateAsTimestamp><ignoreProcedureReturnValues>false</ignoreProcedureReturnValues><unsignedTypes>true</unsignedTypes><integerDisplayWidths>true</integerDisplayWidths><inputCatalog></inputCatalog><outputCatalogToDefault>false</outputCatalogToDefault><inputSchema></inputSchema><outputSchemaToDefault>false</outputSchemaToDefault><schemaVersionProvider></schemaVersionProvider><catalogVersionProvider></catalogVersionProvider><orderProvider></orderProvider><forceIntegerTypesOnZeroScaleDecimals>true</forceIntegerTypesOnZeroScaleDecimals><logSlowQueriesAfterSeconds>5</logSlowQueriesAfterSeconds><logSlowResultsAfterSeconds>5</logSlowResultsAfterSeconds><properties><property><key>packages</key><value>com.ormtester.jpa.domain</value></property><property><key>useAttributeConverters</key><value>true</value></property><property><key>unqualifiedSchema</key><value>none</value></property><property><key>hibernate.physical_naming_strategy</key><value>org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy</value></property></properties></database></generator>
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Configuration.getBasedir()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.run0(GenerationTool.java:272)
    at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.run(GenerationTool.java:225)
    at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.generate(GenerationTool.java:220)
    at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.main(GenerationTool.java:192)
```

However when I will remove the *jooq-config.xml* file then the error is straigtly telling me that the configuration file cannot be found.

I tried to debug the GenerationTool methods but I cannot find the problematic place. I'm unable to designate the source of the problem, so I'll be grateful for every help from Yours side. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Launch `mvn dependency:tree` and check resolved version of `jooq-codegen` and `jooq-meta`. Do they match your expectations?

Comment: @Lesiak both of the libraries have exactly the same versions as defined in the pom file - 3.13.5.

Comment: Let's exclude obvious errors first: try "Reload All Maven Projects" in IntelliJ. `org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Configuration.getBasedir()` returning a `String` is defined in `jooq-meta:3.13.5`, so it must be some kind of project setup error

Comment: @Lesiak I've done it many times (including the attempt done right now to be completely exact), even along with IDEA's cache invalidation and error is still identical.

Comment: You've probably tried this as well: add `-verbose:class` VM option to your run configuration and check where `org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Configuration` is loaded from

Comment: @Lesiak, I haven't done this thing. I've tried now and the `Configuration` class seems to be loaded from library of version 3.12.3 from local maven repo. So I will try to remove it and fetch it again.

Comment: Ok, `Configuration` from `jooq-meta:3.12.3` does not have `getBasedir()` method so this explains the error. My guess is that you have some version management set up by spring, which overrides `3.13.5`. Please share the entire `pom.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot pulls in a set of default jOOQ library versions, which you can verify using the instructions that you got in the comments (mostly `mvn dependency:tree`). The error you're getting hints at there being incompatible versions on your classpath.

If your own version differs from that pulled in by spring boot, you might need to tell spring boot not to pull in any jOOQ versions, and pull them all in yourself, e.g. using this approach [documented in this blog post here](https://blog.jooq.org/2019/06/26/how-to-use-jooqs-commercial-distributions-with-spring-boot/)

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jooq</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
      <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, following the tips given by @Lukas and @Lesiak in this topic I have figured out the solution. As You can see in the initial pom's content I have added the `jooq-codegen` and `jooq-meta-extensions` keeping the versions `3.13.5` and I was sure that "under the hood" those depencies are holding the same versions of the `jooq` and `jooq-meta` libs but unfortunately there were `3.12.3` in both cases. So firstly I have checked the tips that came from @Lukas and then I had to exclude those libs from from the dependencies and add them as the separate dependencies using the right version numbers.

I'm also talking about the `jooq` (where the initial problem was only with `jooq-meta`) because after the problem with `Configuration` class has been resolved, I've faced similar problem with `org.jooq.SQLDialect, as following:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> org.jooq.SQLDialect.supportedBy([Lorg/jooq/SQLDialect;)Ljava/util/Set;
> at org.jooq.meta.AbstractDatabase.(AbstractDatabase.java:117)
> at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  at
> java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)   at
> org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.loadClass0(GenerationTool.java:983)
> at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.loadClass(GenerationTool.java:930)
> at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.run0(GenerationTool.java:395)    at
> org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.run(GenerationTool.java:225)  at
> org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.generate(GenerationTool.java:220)     at
> org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.main(GenerationTool.java:192)

And as I said it also came with the version mismatch, in this case with `jooq`.

After all those changes my pom's content is:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
            <version>3.13.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-meta-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>3.13.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jooq-meta</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-meta</artifactId>
            <version>3.13.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen</artifactId>
            <version>3.13.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jooq-meta</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jibx-tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

And here I can give You a small hint - if You have a tables named with pluralized form and You want fastly depluralize them to keep names of the generated classes singular, You have to add the last depencency from the pom's snippet, create Your own class that extends `DefaultGeneratorStrategy` and overvrite the `getJavaClassName()` method's body with the following fragment:

```
String javaClassName = super.getJavaClassName(definition, mode);
        boolean hasRecordSuffix = javaClassName.contains("Record");
        javaClassName = javaClassName.replace("Record", "");
        String val = nameTools.depluralize(javaClassName);
        if (hasRecordSuffix)
            val += "Record";
        return val;
```

Then simply add Your custom naming strategy to the xml config. Works like a charm, made using this project:
[link](https://github.com/travellingfreak/jooq-plural-to-singular-naming-strategy)

I'm really grateful to You, @Lukas and @Lesiak, thanks for this help!